# Prove $\exists M \gt 0$ s.t. $\Vert f \Vert_1 \leq M \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \ \forall f \in C[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove $\exists M \gt 0$ s.t. $\Vert f \Vert_1 \leq M \Vert f$
>   $\Vert_{\infty}, \ \forall f \in C[-1,1]$.
>
> Where,
>
> $C[-1,1] = \{f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R} | f $ is continuous $\}$
>
> $\Vert f \Vert_1 = \int_0^1 |f|$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$ is the supremum norm.

Now in order to prove this, I drew some pictures to understand what's going on and the answer seems deceptively simple. So simple, that I suspect that I am missing something.

Let $f \in C[-1,1]$ be any function s.t. $f \in \mathscr{R}[0,1]$ also. Then $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$. So $\Vert f \Vert_1$ is bounded.

We know $\Vert f \Vert_1 \leq \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$ since $\Vert f \Vert_1$ is just the area under the curve on $[0.1]$.

So isn't it true the inequality holds for all $f$ with $M = 1$?

I would like to see gaps in my understanding as well as hints towards either a correct proof or a better proof (if my argument is correct).

Thank you

Comment: I should have added that I am assuming $f$ has to be bounded on $[0,1]$ since we are taking the $L^1$ norm (am I right to assume so?). And that, if $f$ is not bounded on $[-1,0)$, then the inequality still holds.

Comment: Are you sure that $||f||_1=\int_{0}^{1} |f|$ instead of $||f||_1=\int_{-1}^{1} |f|$

Comment: Now that you raise that question, I am not sure. I think I was blindly following the definition in my lecture notes. So if the domain is $[a,b]$, then $L^1$ norm is taken over that domain? That is, $[0,1]$ is not part of the definition of $L^1$ norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the triangle equality for integrals. Note that we consider the integral $[-1,1]$, not $[0,1]$. This means that we have $||f||_1 = \int_{-1}^1 |f| \leq \int_{-1}^1 ||f||_\infty = 2||f||_\infty$, so $M = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous functions on compact intervals are necessarily bounded, there is no need to assume it, and the bound should be taken as $2$, as $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}1dx=2$.